# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty

Tags: android, supercsv

I am using an external library called superCSV and this library apparently makes use of isEmpty. After a search on SO, I found that this method was introduced in 2.3 and indeed the crash I am getting is from 2.2

Is there anyway I can fix it that while still using the library? Perhaps provide an implementation of isEmpty? or somehow get it not to crash?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of SuperCSV?
This has been fixed with SuperCSV 2.0.1 (and higher) by [restoring Java 5 compatibility](http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/discussion/718794/thread/18386739/).

You can see the related commit here: http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/code/264/

Instead of calling `java.lang.String.isEmpty()` the library is now doing a simple check for `String.length() == 0`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Perfect! I guess I didn't realize they introduced a new version.

Comment: Thanks @Jens, you beat me to it :) It's funny that the only people to report this are Android devs (both this question and the bug on SF were) - we were in beta for 2.0.0 for a month or so and no users picked it up (until after the release). So I'm guessing Java 5 is on the decline finally, though as I mentioned on SF, Android pre-Gingerbread is based on Java 5, so I had to fix it pretty quick ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source of the library, change the call to from isEmpty() to equals("").

If you don't have the source of the library, not really.

Comment: The source is available at http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/. You could also try changing the Java compiler for the project to 1.6 instead of 1.5.